# Can't locate node ardrone_driver node in ardrone_autonomy package

Tags: ros, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although this has been asked [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/206832/error-cannot-launch-node-of-type-cant-locate-node-in-package/) before, there was no solution.

**Background**: I am using a real-drone ( not ROS simulation ) I have been trying to follow [this](http://robohub.org/up-and-flying-with-the-ar-drone-and-ros-getting-started/)  tutorial ( I'm not using a VM ) for which I need to install the ardrone_autonomy package by -

1. installing binary directly using `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy` .
2. Cloning source from github ( `git clone https://github.com/tum-vision/ardrone_autonomy.git` ) and then `./build_sdk.sh` didn't build due to some errors.

Since method 2) didn't build, after **I used method 1)**  and ran  the command (`roslaunch ardrone_tutorials keyboard_controller_outdoor.launch`) from the tutorial  I got the following error -

`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ardrone_autonomy/ardrone_driver]: can't locate node [ardrone_driver] in package [ardrone_autonomy]`

**The issue:** I can't seem to find the ardrone_driver file anywhere. ( I tried using linux `find` ). There are other few other errors too (unrelated hence not shown above, just mentioning for completeness).

**System specs**: Ubuntu Xenial  and ROS kinetic.

Please help.

Thanks!

**Update:**

`rospack find ardrone_autonomy` gives  `/home/malhar/catkin_ws/src/ardrone_autonomy`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278212/can%27t-locate-node-ardrone_driver-node-in-ardrone_autonomy-package./) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2017-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-26**:
Did you install the `ardrone_autonomy` package? That tutorial (which is quite old!) uses the `ardrone_autonomy` package to connect with the drone. Also, do you have the actual drone or are you using a simulator?

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2017-12-26**:
Thanks for replying @jayess , yes I used `apt-get` to install `ardrone_autonomy` ( I have also updated the question )

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-26**:
Where did you search for it? Please update your question with the result of `rospack find ardrone_autonomy`.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-27**:
Are you sourcing your `setup.bash`?

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2017-12-27**:
`rospack find ardrone_autonomy` gives the correct file path (`/home/malhar/catkin_ws/src/ardrone_autonomy` ) to the package folder.

I'm not certain why you want me to find the ardrone_autonomy package. As mentioned in the question,  I am unable to find the ardrone_driver node,

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-27**:
That location is actually *not* the correct directory if you used `apt` to install the package. It should be in your `/opt/ros/kinetic/share` directory. If you plan on using the `apt` installed version. Try deleting this one, recompile, and `source` your `setup.bash`.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2017-12-27**:
Ok thanks, I understand. I removed the github source installations from my catkin_ws. However, now `rospack` cannot find the `ardrone_autonomy` package.

Do I have to be connected to the drone wifi for rospack to be able to find ardrone_autonomy ? ( I don't think so but would like to confirm )

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-12-27**:
If you haven't already, delete the `~/catkin_ws/build` and `~/catkin_ws/devel` directories and rebuild using `catkin_make` or whatever build tool you're using.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-12-27**:
Or, as a quick check, you can ignore your compiled version by sourcing `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and then running `rospack find ardrone_autonomy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You still have the package that you downloaded from GitHub in your workspace which is why when you run `rospack find ardrone_autonomy` you see that it's located in `~/catkin_ws/src/ardrone_autonomy`.

Follow these steps:

1. Delete this package along with the `~/catkin_ws/build`, `~/catkin_ws/devel`, and `~/catkin_ws/install` directories (as noted by @clyde )
2. Compile your workspace again.
3. Now, `source` (ROS if you're not doing that already and) your workspace:

   ```
   $ source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash
       $ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
   ```
4. Run

   ```
   $ roslaunch ardrone_tutorials keyboard_controller_outdoor.launch
   ```

again and `roslaunch` should be able to find the `ardrone_driver` node. Note that to *find* and *launch* the node you don't have to be connected to your drone. But, to *use* it you do need to be connected to the drone.

Please update your question if this still doesn't fix your issue.

**Note:** I've moved the question's comments into this answer.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-10**:
If this answer solved your problem, please click on the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-01-11**:
Hi, sorry for the delay... I will quickly get back to this in a day.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-31**:
@malharjajoo: if this solved your problem please click on the check mark to mark it as the correct answer.